# How to read "Vertically" from data sets such as CSV

Tags: java

So my issue right now is that I'm really unsure of how to read data "vertically". As an example:

A    B    C    D    E    F

1    4    1    3    5    8

2    3    1    3    6    4

3    2    1    3    7    5

4    1    1    3    7    4

I have to manipulate this data in a few ways. I'm pretty fine with anything on the same line although I'm clueless as to how to compare items from the same column. One objective I am trying to achieve is to re-write this with only attributes that have more than one domain. So in this instance, C, D, and all the numbers below them should be omitted.

```
public void dataProcessing(){

    File file = new File("insertFilePathHere");

    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        //Please ignore these, they are more relevant to the actual data set
        String titles = input.nextLine();
        String types = input.nextLine();

        int i = 0;
        while (input.hasNext()){
            String line = input.nextLine();
            //This is refering to a line that is incomplete, they are to be removed
            if (line.contains("?")){
                continue;
            }
            //For printing what i have back into a table to check results
            String[] row = line.split(" ");
            for(String index : row){
                System.out.printf("%10s", index);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, read about multidimensional array, it will be a good start

Comment: If you can store the entire data set in the computer memory, then you need to use an appropriate [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure). Nonetheless, the purpose of a [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) is to manipulate data sets. It appears that you may be [reinventing the wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel).

Comment: *So in this instance, C, D, and all the numbers below them should be omitted.* So why not skip those columns?

Comment: Incidentally, most csv APIs have the ability to view the file as `String[][]`. Skipping columns also supported I think

Answer (score 1):

I'd solve the problem this way:

- use a **2D Array** (new XXX[][])
- read/scan the file LineByLine (two for/while-loops)
- write those lines into the array

and then you should be able to work with that array

**It should look something like this** (I'm sorry if there are any wrong Functions or Errors because I'm coding this without an IDE with SyntaxHighlighting or IntelliSense - there shouldn't be any Errors though):

```
char[][] arr = new char[rows][cols];
Scanner scanCol = new Scanner(file);

//if you know the #rows and #cols
for(int col = 0; x < cols; x++) {
    Scanner scanRow = new Scanner(scanCol.nextLine());

    for(int row = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        //incase an Exception comes up
        try {
            char currChar = scanRow.next().charAt(row); 
            arr[col][row] = currChar;
        } catch (Exception e) { //you could also write IndexOutOfBoundsException e
            break;
        }
    
    }
}

//if you only know the #cols
for(int col = 0; x < cols; x++) {
    Scanner scanRow = new Scanner(scanCol.nextLine());

    int row = 0;
    while(true) { //unfortunately there's no function called hasNextChar()
        try {
            char currChar = scanRow.next().charAt(row); 
            arr[col][row] = currChar;
        } catch (Exception e) { //you could also write IndexOutOfBoundsException e
            break;
        }
        row++;
    }
}

//the top one but in a cleaner way if inline ifs work in while-Loops
int totalRows = 0;
for(int col = 0; x < cols; x++) {
    Scanner scanRow = new Scanner(scanCol.nextLine());

    int row = 0;
    while(row=0?true:(row < totalRows)) {
        try {
            char currChar = scanRow.next().charAt(row); 
            arr[col][row] = currChar;
        } catch (Exception e) { //you could also write IndexOutOfBoundsException e
            break;
        }
        row++;
    }
    totalRows = row;
}

//if you just know the file exists ;)
while(scanCol.hasNextLine()) {
    Scanner scanRow = new Scanner(scanCol.nextLine());

    int row = 0;
    while(true) {
        try {
            char currChar = scanRow.next().charAt(row); 
            arr[col][row] = currChar;
        } catch (Exception e) { //you could also write IndexOutOfBoundsException e
            break;
        }
        row++;
    }
}


//to find out how many cols and rows there are
scanCol = new Scanner(file);
int cols = 0;
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    cols++;
    scan.nextLine();
}

scanRow = new Scanner(new Scanner(file).nextLine());
while(true) {
    try {
        scanRow.nextChar();
        rows++;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Please feel free to correct me or ask questions about my solution!